# how to check if 2 rows are symmetrical?

Tags: javascript

i have 2 rows that i need to check in java script if they are symmetrical

row 1 [2, 7, 9, 9, 7, 2]  row 2 [5 7 3 3 7 5] how would you do it ?

```
var r = [[5, 7, 3, 3, 7, 5], [2, 7, 9, 9, 7, 2]];

function isSymmetric(r) {
// convert to object
var rel = {}
for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    if (!(r[i][0] in rel)) rel[r[i][0]] = {};
    rel[r[i][0]][r[i][1]] = true;
}
// Test to see if opposite relation is in object
for (var a in rel) {
    for (var b in rel[a]) {
        if (!rel[b] || !rel[b][a]) return false;
    }
}

return true;
}

console.log(isSymmetric(r));
```

Comment: how do you define symmetrical?

Comment: Dirty method: `isSymmetric = r => r.toString() === r.slice().reverse().toString()`

Comment: please add what *symmetrical* means in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
let isSymmetric = arr => {
  for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] !== arr[arr.length - (i+1)])
      return false
  }
  return true
}

console.log(isSymmetric([5, 7, 3, 3, 7, 5]))
console.log(isSymmetric([1, 7, 9, 9, 7, 2]))
```

The idea is to loop through the array and for each index compare with its "sibling" from the right side. If one is not the same them return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `lodash`.

```
var row = [2, 7, 9, 9, 7, 2];
var halves = _.chunk(row, _.ceil(row.length / 2));
var result = _.isEqual(halves[0], _.reverse(halves[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start from `0`th index and compare the value with its symmetric pair (`length - 1 - i`), and if they are not same then `return false`. You should stop at the middle `length / 2`:

```js
let values = [
 [5, 7, 3, 3, 7, 5], 
 [2, 7, 9, 1, 9, 7, 2],
 [5, 7, 3, 3, 7, 1]
];


function isSymmetric(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length / 2; i++) {
    if (arr[i] !== arr[arr.length - 1 - i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return true;
}

values.forEach(v => 
  console.log(isSymmetric(v))
);
```